# Rabbitmq message not delivering / tools for low-level rabbitmq debugging?

Tags: logging, rabbitmq

I'm fighting a nasty rabbitmq-related issue at the moment where one part of my system is publishing a message, but the process I expect to be consuming that message sometimes (like 1 message out of a hundred, more frequently when the whole system is under heavy load) fails to receive the message. As far as I can tell the message is going in to the exchange but it's not coming out. My gut is that this has something to do with a race condition with my topic bindings or something, but I have basically no tools to inspect rabbitmq's internal state.

My dream tool would be something where I could essentially `tail -f` an exchange's logs and see all operations on that exchange (create, bind, unbind, publish). This might help me see exactly what rabbit is seeing and why my messages are occasionally failing to be delivered to the queue I'm expecting them too.

Does such a thing exist? I've played with the rabbitmqadmin plugin, but it seems way more high level than this. I've looked at rabbit's built in logging but it seems to just keep track of client connections. Is there a config file option to turn up the verbosity of that log? Or some other log file that has what I'm looking for? Clearly this level of verbosity would destroy a production cluster, but I could really use it during development. I've also contemplated writing a separate logging process to just subscribe to `#` on the topic exchange, but since part of what I'm concerned about is the timing of binding/unbinding it would be a pretty crude solution.

Comment: Are you using a single topic exchange? How many queues are bound to the topic? What sort of load are you putting the system under? Is it possible your processor is getting the message, but experiencing an error?

Comment: The issue in question is for a single topic exchange with ~10 queues bound to various topic configurations. I think I've seen it at throughputs as low as a hundred msg/s.

Comment: I should say that I figured out the proximate issue - it was a queue binding timing issue. Started setting mandatory on publishes that I knew should succeed and retrying until they did. This is bad long-term practice, but at least identified the problem. In any event, the core question is I think still relevant: are there any tools that can inspect activity at this level?